# JavaScript login form

Tags: javascript

I'm here because i just lear javascript and I have an issuse with a login page for just one user.
The code works perfectly fine if you wrong, but when you type everything correctly, the page just refreshes.
I tried with "location = "" " and
    window.open
but the same error.
Here is some code:

```
function login(form) {
if (form.id.value=="a") { 
if (form.pass.value=="b") {              
window.location.assign("file.html")
} else {
alert("Error! \n Invalid password. \n Please try again.")
}
} else {  alert("Error! \n Invalid username. \n Please try again!")
}
}

</script>

<form method="POST">

<input type="text" id="name" class="textbox" placeholder="Username" name="id"></input><br/>

<input type="password" id="pass" class="textbox" placeholder="Password" name="pass"></input><br/>

<input type="submit" id="send" value="Log in" class="submit" onClick="login(this.form);"></input>

</form>
```

Some help here?

Comment: I'd be careful with trying to validate passwords in javascript.  It's VERY easy to see what valid values are...

Comment: It is just for learning and testing.

Comment: @user2366842 Considering the basic levelness of this application, I wouldn't be worried about best practices. It's highly likely Popa Gabiel is in the process of learning the language.

Comment: I just want to see the issuse.

Comment: I can't learn php without js. It's basically.

Comment: IMO, best practices should always be kept in mind, especially when first learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to redirect to your desired location, your method needs to return `false` to prevent the default action (I also took the liberty of cleaning up your `username` and `password` checks).

```
<script>
    function login(form) {
        if (form.id.value === "a" && form.pass.value === "b") {
            window.location.assign("file.html");
        } else {
            alert("Error! \n Invalid username or password. \n Please try again!");
        }
        return false;//add this here
    }
</script>
```

And change your submit button to return the value of the method call:

```
<input type="submit" id="send" value="Log in" class="submit" onclick="return login(this.form);"/>
```

You should then receive your desired results. In the future it will be better to check these values and perform redirects on the server side (PHP for example).